# Removing border-radius in Bootstrap 4 | list-group-item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am new to bootstrap and have been over riding bootstrap border-radius property with my custom CSS class.

```css
.border-radius-none{
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Image:

[image]

This does work for all the cases but while over riding `list-group-item`, first and last element are not over ridden.

1. My main css is linked below the bootstrap css.(As in below snippet)
2. Read [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on CSS specificity, which doesn't help me out.

**Things I tried**

1. Added `!important` to my css.

Is there any other way to remove bootstrap border-radius default value, without using important ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="./Main.css" rel="stylesheet">


<li class="list-group-item bg-black white-text border-none">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9"> Latest Jobs </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <a href="#" class="mr-auto">View all</a>
        </div>


    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: what the problem with `!important` it is the way to prevent override

Comment: But I've read that, it is not the right way to solve, 'because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your style sheets'. As per the article mentioned in the link.

Comment: but that the only way you can override bootstrap

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some of the class are predefined in bootstrap as per the documentation `class="rounded-0"` which will set `border-radius` to `0`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-radius

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item rounded-0">Cat</li>
     <li class="list-group-item rounded-0">Dog</li>
     <li class="list-group-item rounded-0">Rabbit</li>
     <li class="list-group-item rounded-0">Alpaca</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this class to your css  to override `.list-group-item` or `.list-group-item:last-child` and place the link to your css after the boostrap css link

```
    .list-group-item{
                border-radius: 0;
     }
```

or

```
.list-group-item:last-child{
                border-radius: 0;
     }
```

Comment: He has already this and trying to avoid !important in his CSS.

Comment: Sure I have removed the important already as long as the class is overridden the border-radius will remove

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `.border-radius-none{
    border-radius: 0;
}`

use`.border-radius-none{
    border-radius: none;
}`

And if you do not want to add !important just try specify the class use `.classname>.innerclass{border:none;}`

Comment: There is no value as border-radius: none;

Answer (score 0):

this is other way to write  border-radius: 0; inline

```css
.list-group-item
{
    border-radius: 34px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="./Main.css" rel="stylesheet">


<li class="list-group-item bg-black white-text border-none" style=" border-radius: 0;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9"> Latest Jobs </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <a href="#" class="mr-auto">View all</a>
        </div>


    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: style=" border-radius: 0;"  using style

Comment: This is Bad coding practice!!

Comment: yeap i know but only this way to remove a border-radius without using !important

Comment: this class is alredy in ans so that

Comment: .rounded-0 {
    border-radius: 0!important;
}

Comment: alredy use this class in !important;

Comment: see the question "without using important"

Answer (score 0):

you can check [Calculating CSS Specificity Value](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/#article-header-id-0)

[image]

.list-item-group:first-child is 0,0,2,0( class *1 + psuedo-class *1)

- .list-item-group : 0,0,1,0
- :first-child : 0,0,1,0

.border-none is 0,0,1,0 (class * 1)

---

you have multiple ways to plus your CSS specificity value, the simple way is using two class

```js
.border-none,
.border-none.list-group-item {
   border-radius : 0;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item bg-black white-text border-none">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9"> Latest Jobs </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <a href="#" class="mr-auto">View all</a>
        </div>


    </div>
</li>
```